# How to use upper_bound with a vector of pairs, arranged in increasing order of pair.second, and then pair.first?

Tags: c++, stl

I use the following comparator function to sort my vector of pairs.

```
bool sortbysec(const pair<long long,long long> &a,
          const pair<long long,long long> &b)
{
    if(a.second < b.second)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(a.second==b.second)
    {
        if(a.first<b.first)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now I would like to do `upper_bound` on `pair.second` with a given value. How do I write it's comparator function, so that I can get the first pair where `second = second element`, and first shall be the lowest?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a functor class instead of a plain function. This class could hold a reference to the complete vector as well.

Comment: You can also use a plain function. I don't get the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want `std::lower_bound`, not `upper_bound`. Something like this:

```
auto iter = std::lower_bound(
    your_contaner.begin(),
    your_contaner.end(),
    lookup_second,
    [](const std::pair<long long,long long>& p, long long second) {
      return p.second < second;
    }
);
if (iter != your_contaner.end() && iter->second == lookup_second) {
  // `iter` points to an element with given `second` and smallest `first`.
  // Otherwise, there's no element with given `second`, and `iter` points
  // to the leftmost larger element, or `end()`.
}
```